# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to write a login script that needs a user to to login before they can access the database and when i write out the code i get the login in screen but the screen gives this error:
**PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in G:\xampp\htdocs\music\auth.php on line 12**

I dont know what to do. Heres my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$err = "";
if( !empty($_POST['submit']) )
{
    $name = $_POST['user'];
    $pwd = $_POST['password'];

    $music = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=music', 'musicphp', 'password');
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM music WHERE username = '$name' AND pwd='$pwd'";
    $users= $music->query($sql);
    $music = $users->fetch();

    if( empty($users['id']) || $users == NULL )
    {
        $err = "Bad username or password";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
echo $err;
?>
<form action = "auth.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user"/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why use PDO if not interested in prepared statements ???  :)

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal Why not? PDO is modern, more cross platform, and easy to use. Surely you’re not suggesting `mysql` functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use prepared statement

Remove this part

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM music WHERE username = '$name' AND pwd='$pwd'";
$users= $music->query($sql);
$music = $users->fetch();
```

And Replace it with this

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM music WHERE username = :name AND pwd=:pwd";
$statement= $music->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array(':name'=> $name,':pwd'=>$pwd));
$music =  $statement->fetch();
```

Comment: Where would i put that?

Comment: It worked but appeartnly im locked out of my database

Comment: yea but i dont know wat to do t get back to my database

Comment: Are you saying that you have dropped your database? and you cannot use it?

Comment: it says my access is denied "Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed."

Comment: that would be a different question.Seems like not related to your question above. Because you pdo instance above is correct.

Comment: My error is: **bold**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server' in G:\xampp\htdocs\music\auth.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 G:\xampp\htdocs\music\auth.php(11): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'musicphp', 'password')
#1 {main}
  thrown in G:\xampp\htdocs\music\auth.php on line 11**bold**

Comment: are you sure that your user is musicphp? and the password of the user is password? The default user is root and it doesnt have a password.

Comment: try this pdo connection `= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=music', 'root', '');`

Comment: Please if my answer is correct for you kindly click the check icon for me?